# Shell function/alias for rails console/server etc, to work with rails 2 & 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ruby-on-rails-3, zsh

Rails 3 introduced the `rails {c,s,g}` command format for invoking the console, server, generators and so on.

Back with rails 2 I had `alias c=script/console` and others set up to alleviate typing.

I'd like the same for rails 3 but I still maintain rails 2 apps. Could I have a shell alias/function/other that checked for the existence of script/foo and ran it if present, else run the rails 3 equivalents?

Sorry for the lazy question; bash/zsh scripting is designed to rot one's brane imho and I'm rather hoping someone will have tackled this already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-f` test

`alias c="if [ -f script/console ]; then script/console; else script/rails console; fi"`

Comment: Cool, that works. I get `zsh: no such file or directory: script/console` with a rails3 app but it goes on to the alternate command. Cheers.

Comment: I updated my answer; I realized the logical OR could make the second command run for different reasons other than simply not existing.

Comment: Such as if the command eventually exited with a non-zero return value?

Comment: Thanks @Andy. I like that your command uses `script/rails` which should avoid creating a new rails app when neither command is present but rails 2 is in $PATH.